# Error with Roo . Any gems to parse .ods files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openoffice-calc

I am trying to use the roo gem to parse an Openoffice spreadsheet. However I am getting the following error while beginning my localhost

/home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/roo-1.9.3/lib/roo/openoffice.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- zip/zipfilesystem (LoadError)

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/roo-1.9.3/lib/roo/openoffice.rb:3:in `'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/roo-1.9.3/lib/roo.rb:68:in `require'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/roo-1.9.3/lib/roo.rb:68:in `'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'

from /home/raison/anna/config/application.rb:7:in `'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in '

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'

from /home/raison/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `'

from script/rails:6:in `require'

from script/rails:6:in `'

I already have rubyzip installed. Can anyone help me out here? Also please suggest some alternate gems for parsing .ods files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gemfile

gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zipfilesystem'

Answer (score 1):

[Rspreadsheet](https://github.com/gorn/rspreadsheet) allows you to read, modify and write ods files. Here is the example of its basic usage

```ruby
require 'rspreadsheet'

# initialization
book = Rspreadsheet.open('./test.ods')
sheet = book.worksheets(1)

# get value of a cell B5 (there are more ways to do this)
sheet.B5                       # => 'cell value'
sheet[5,2]                     # => 'cell value'
sheet.rows(5).cells(2).value   # => 'cell value'

# set value of a cell B5
sheet.F5 = 'text'
sheet[5,2] = 7
sheet.cells(5,2).value = 1.78

# working with cell format
sheet.cells(5,2).format.bold = true
sheet.cells(5,2).format.background_color = '#FF0000'

# calculating sum of cells in row
sheet.rows(5).cellvalues.sum
sheet.rows(5).cells.sum{ |cell| cell.value.to_f }

# iterating over list of people and displaying the data

total = 0
sheet.rows.each do |row|
  puts "Sponsor #{row[1]} with email #{row[2]} has donated #{row[3]} USD."
  total += row[3].to_f
end
puts "Totally fundraised #{total} USD"

# saving file
book.save
book.save('different_filename.ods')
```

The project is under active developments and I use it in my projects. Any comments are welcomed. If you are migging a feature, you may [fill in the request](https://github.com/gorn/rspreadsheet/issues) and it will be implemented.